# Как в Ext.Net серверно отключить атрибут OnEvent?

Tags: asp.net, extjs

В моем aspx есть кнопка:

```
<ext:Button runat="server" ID="SaveButton"
                    Text="Save"
                    Icon="PageSave"
                    meta:resourcekey="SaveButton">
                    <DirectEvents>
                        <Click OnEvent="SaveData">
                            <EventMask ShowMask="True"></EventMask>
                        </Click>
                    </DirectEvents>
                </ext:Button>
```

Из-за архитектуры приложения редактировать aspx не имею права. Как можно на C# или JS написать отмену OnEvent? То есть, чтобы указанный метод SaveData не сработал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ, оказывается, был прост:

```
SaveButton.DirectEvents.Click.Event -= SaveData;
```